# Is there a Subversion command to reset the working copy?

Tags: svn

Is there a single Subversion command that would “reset” a working copy exactly to the state that’s stored in the repository? Something like `git reset --hard` or (ha, hard Git reset does not remove unversioned files either!) `rm -rf wc && svn co <url> wc`.

*Update:* I’m not after a simple revert, as that does not delete extra files in the working copy. I really want something that would be the same as deleting the working copy and checking it out again, only without having to download the data again. (Obviously I don’t mind losing all the uncommitted changes.)

Comment: reverting all changes in the working copy?

Comment: You'd use `git clean -xdf` to remove things that aren't under source control.

Comment: @vcsjones: Thanks, the man page for `git clean` quotes exactly what I am looking for: “This can be used (possibly in conjunction with git reset) to create a pristine working directory to test a clean build.” Pity that Subversion does not seem to have anything like this built-in.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You can recursively revert like this:

`svn revert --recursive .`

There is no way (without writing a creative script) to remove things that aren't under source control. I think the closest you could do is to iterate over all of the files, use then grep the result of `svn list`, and if the grep fails, then delete it.

**EDIT**:
The solution for the creative script is here: [Automatically remove Subversion unversioned files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239340/automatically-remove-subversion-unversioned-files)

So you could create a script that combines a `revert` with whichever answer in the linked question suits you best.

Comment: You might want to run `svn cleanup` on the wc first as well. This is my standard practice for cleaning up after aborted merges and whatnot.

Comment: tortoise also has an option "remove unversioned files" in the cleanup dialog.

Comment: It would be nice if the "remove unversioned files" was available via command line. Especially for automated builds.

Comment: See my answer... --remove-unversioned exists for svn cleanup

Answer (score 45):

### To revert tracked files

```
svn revert . -R
```

### To clean untracked files

```
svn status | rm -rf $(awk '/^?/{$1 = ""; print $0}')
```

The `-rf` may/should look scary at first, but once understood it will not be for these reasons:

1. Only wholly-untracked directories will match the pattern passed to `rm`
2. The `-rf` is required, else these directories will not be removed

### To revert then clean (the OP question)

```
svn revert . -R && svn status | rm -rf $(awk '/^?/{$1 = ""; print $0}')
```

### For consistent ease of use

Add permanent alias to your .bash_aliases

```
alias svn.HardReset='read -p "destroy all local changes?[y/N]" && [[ $REPLY =~ ^[yY] ]] && svn revert . -R && rm -rf $(awk -f <(echo "/^?/{print \$2}") <(svn status) ;)'
```

Comment: the 2nd snippet does not seem to work for me: `awk: fatal: error reading input file '-': Input/output error`

Comment: I had to escape the `?` in the `awk` command, otherwise it matched all lines in the output of `svn status`

Answer (score 25):

Delete everything inside your local copy using:

```
rm -r your_local_svn_dir_path/*
```

And the revert everything recursively using the below command.

```
svn revert -R your_local_svn_dir_path
```

This is way faster than deleting the entire directory and then taking a fresh checkout, because the files are being restored from you local SVN meta data. It doesn't even need a network connection.

Comment: much faster is svn cleanup --remove-unversioned   .

Answer (score 14):

**Delete unversioned files and revert any changes:**

```
svn revert D:\tmp\sql -R
svn cleanup D:\tmp\sql --remove-unversioned
```

Out:

```
D         D:\tmp\sql\update\abc.txt
```

Comment: this is the best answer, without additional scripting. this is universal and compatible with many svn versions.

Comment: I needed/wanted `svn cleanup --remove-ignored` too.  Still - best answer here.

Answer (score 7):

```
svn revert . -R
```

to reset everything.

```
svn revert path/to/file
```

for a single file

Comment: That does not delete extra unversioned files in the working copy, does it?

Comment: @zoul I don't think so, but don't quote me on that since it's been awhile since I used SVN

Comment: unfortunately it does not touch not tracked files. try svn revert -R your_local_svn_dir_path

Answer (score 3):

Pure Windows cmd/bat solution:

```
svn cleanup .
svn revert -R .
For /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in ('svn status --no-ignore') Do (
     If [%%A]==[?] ( Call :UniDelete %%B
     ) Else If [%%A]==[I] Call :UniDelete %%B
   )
svn update .
goto :eof

:UniDelete delete file/dir
IF EXIST "%1\*" (
    RD /S /Q "%1"
) Else (
    If EXIST "%1" DEL /S /F /Q "%1"
)
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete the working copy from the OS and check it out again is simplest, but obviously not a single command.

Comment: Painfully slow. That’s why I was looking for a way around this.

Answer (score 2):

Very quick and simple and does exactly what you want

```
svn status | awk '{if($2 !~ /(config|\.ini)/ && !system("test -e \"" $2 "\"")) {print $2; system("rm -Rf \"" $2 "\"");}}'
```

The /(config|.ini)/ is for my own purposes.

And might be a good idea to add --no-ignore to the svn command

Comment: This is so awful. What about Windows users?  Subversion obviously needs a bit of work before it can be taken seriously as a version control tool.

Answer (score 1):

## To remove untracked files

I was able to list all untracked files reported by `svn st` in bash by doing:

```
echo $(svn st | grep -P "^\?" | cut -c 9-)
```

If you are feeling lucky, you could replace `echo` with `rm` to delete untracked files. Or copy the files you want to delete by hand, if you are feeling a less lucky.

---

(I used @abe-voelker 's answer to revert the remaining files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6204601/1695680)