# Does svn have a `revert-all` command?

Tags: svn, command-line

If I want to throw away all of my changes, and return to the code that is on the repository, I do the following:

```
$ rm -fr *
$ svn up
```

This is easy enough, but I'm wondering if there is a single command that will accomplish this, something like:

```
$ svn revert-all
```

Comment: Who uses -fr instead of -rf? There's a reason it's pronounced rimraf, not rimfer.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa What is the reason?

Comment: convention's Wilson! Conventions, sir! Without our discipline and cultural traditions, we are but savages! I say, good day sir!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239340/automatically-remove-subversion-unversioned-files | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204572/is-there-a-subversion-command-to-reset-the-working-copy

Answer (score 322, accepted):

You could do:

```
svn revert -R .
```

This will not delete any new file not under version control. But you can easily write a shell script to do that like:

```
for file in `svn status|grep "^ *?"|sed -e 's/^ *? *//'`; do rm $file ; done
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for a thorough answer, as `svn revert -R` isn't equivalent to the two commands I gave.

Comment: For removing all files not under version control in  Windows command line, the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1502365/1385429

Comment: User [mashzo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3745505/mashzo) pointed out (in a now-deleted answer) that the `-R` flag may be necessary to ensure that unversioned directories are also deleted, as part of throwing away *all* changes. Consider incorporating this into your answer, if that seems appropriate to you.

Answer (score 30):

There is a command

```
svn revert -R .
```

**OR**
you can  use the --depth=infinity, which is actually same as above:

```
svn revert --depth=infinity
```

`svn revert` is inherently dangerous, since its entire purpose is to throw away data—namely, your uncommitted changes. Once you've reverted, Subversion provides no way to get back those uncommitted changes

Comment: `-R` is equivalent to `--depth=infinity`

Comment: Your cmd "svn revert -R" is missing the current directory in the syntax.. it should be "svn revert -R ."

Comment: Currently, the post sounds like `-R` is mutually exclusive to `--depth-infinity` when it's not.

Comment: @ahnbizcad Aren't those two exact synonyms anyway?

Comment: That's my point. This answer makes the two sound different when it's not. "mutually exclusive" = opposite of synonym

Answer (score 19):

Use the recursive switch --recursive (-R)

```
svn revert -R .
```

Answer (score 0):

To revert modified files:

```
sudo svn revert
svn status|grep "^ *M" | sed -e 's/^ *M *//'
```

Comment: I think my formatting change represents what you want. Rollback if you don't like it. And thanks, it's good to remember the bad old days of SVN ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Two commands:

```
svn revert -R .
svn cleanup --remove-unversioned .
```

The first command reverts the versioned files and the second remove all the unversioned files

Answer (score -3):

To revert modified files:

```
svn revert -R <path_to_directory>
```

Comment: This has been mentioned by several other posters. How does your answer defer from their?