# svn command line for override and update local directory

Tags: svn, command, overriding

In order to override and update my local directory with svn commands, what should I write? When I do update, it does not override my local changes. Should I do revert?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes have a look at these simple commands http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/edguide/chapter03.html

Comment: I found it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139605/does-svn-have-a-revert-all-command

Answer (score 0):

This workfor me

```
svn checkout svn://path/to/repo --force
```