# svn-win32 checkout does not discard modifications

Tags: windows, svn, cmd

I am having issues with the command-line client of svn - svn-win32.

Current situation:
We have a directory with multiple subfolders, like so

file1

folder/archives/file2

folder/archives/file3

Situation1:
A new file is added via checkout. 
Everything behaves as it should.

Situation2:
An existing file is modified via checkout.

Result: Existing file remains, and is marked as "modified".

Desired result: Existing file fully overwritten, local changes lost.

### How do i achieve the desired result?

```
svn revert -r pathname
svn up
```

did not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to always (force) overwrite local changes when updating from SVN? Ignore conflicts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709197/is-it-possible-to-always-force-overwrite-local-changes-when-updating-from-svn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn revert` requires a path be passed in; use `svn revert -r .` to discard **all** changes in the current directory and everything below, or specify a directory or file if you want to revert that path and everything below it. *Then* you can run `svn update`.

Comment: Been using 
"%SVN%/svn" revert --depth=infinity -R pathname 
"%SVN%/svn" up pathname

Comment: Resolved.
The reason this solution did not initially work was because a line in the .bat
was pointing towards a different folder in the dir one level above from which the .bat was ran.

This works, thank you.